# Setting the main .tex file in Overleaf v2

Tags: overleaf

Is there a way to define a different .tex file as the main .tex document in Overleaf v2? In Overleaf v1, this can be done through right clicking on a .tex file and choosing "Set as Main File". However, this option does not appear in Overleaf v2 for me.

[image: Setting the main .tex file on Overleaf v1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Overleaf v2, open the project and hit menu. There's an option for changing the main file:

[image]